# Imagemapster highlight based on posted values

Tags: jquery, imagemapster

I am VERY new to jquery, and I am having some difficulty figuring this out.

I have a page with an image map and I set the value initially in the window.load function:

```
    $('img').mapster('highlight', 'Lot_15:1');
```

What I would like to do is IF there is data posted to the page, change this default highlight to an area that is specified by data posted from another page in lieu of 'Lot_15:1'.  i.e. form.request("HighlightArea") <> "" then ...

Answer (score 0):

Programatically created a hidden input and set the value of the input.  Then retrieved the value from the input when the jquery is called.  I am sure there is a more elegant way, but it works.